# Python: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'lines.txt'

Tags: python, visual-studio-2010, python-3.x

I have the python tool on Visual Studio 2010.
I tried to open a text file, which is in the same folder with the .py file, but I am having

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'lines.txt'

Here is the line:

```
fh = open('lines.txt')
```

please help.

Comment: Are you sure you are spelling it correctly and that the extension is `.txt`?

Comment: yes. It is running when I use the python shell, but not in visual studio.

Comment: How are you running your python script. By navigating to the directory and doing `python script.py` or by doing `python C:\folder\folder\script.py`

Comment: C:\folder\folder\script.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is your problem, if you're going to run the script as `C:\folder\folder\script.py`, then your code will try to look for `input.txt` in `C:`. You should first navigate to the folder and *then* run the script simply as `script.py` or `python script.py`.

Answer (score 1):

You should add folder's address to the code just like this.

```
f = open("E:\\python\\201607final\\names.txt","r")
```